# account information breadcrumbs in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, breadcrumbs

I have added below to code to get the breadcrumb for account information section:

```
<customer_account_edit translate="label">
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
          <crumbName>Account Information</crumbName>
          <crumbInfo>
               <label>Account Information</label>
               <title>Account Information</title>
          </crumbInfo>
       </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

but iam not getting full bread crumb url.

screenshot:

https://prnt.sc/igd4ci

Can any one help me what is the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Which code you have added?

Comment: please find the code in the question

Comment: Why you are writing custom breadcrumb? Magento by default show's breadcrumb on Account Edit form

Comment: Thansk, by default for my theme iam having breadcrums issue so, i wants to add it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show full path in custom breadcrumb then you have to specify every breadcrumb element like below code:

```
<action method="addCrumb">
  <crumbName>home</crumbName>
  <crumbInfo translate="label title">
     <label>Home</label>
     <title>Home</title>
     <link>/</link>
  </crumbInfo>
</action>
<action method="addCrumb">
  <crumbName>my_account</crumbName>
  <crumbInfo translate="label title">
    <label>Account Information</label>
    <title>Account Information</title>
    <link>customer/account/edit</link>
  </crumbInfo>
</action>
```